# Unwanted changes in attribute table after processing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, arcgis-10.6

I am currently having issues with the [Eliminate Polygon Parts](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate-polygon-part.htm) tool (Cartography Toolbox). I have an Advanced License and ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1. I run the tool on a polygon feature class, in order to delete features < 20 m2. The resulting polygons look fine. However, there is quite a problem with the attribute table of the feature class - it gets messed up completely.

I have 4 fields (int_300 / tiefe_300 / pq_id / p_typ), containing coded information (short integers). Some of the fields and information was added using the `arcpy.AddField_management()` and `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()` tools. The information in the fields need to remain the same for further processing, but they don't. Somehow the "shape_length" and "shape_area" fields get moved to "pq_id" and "p_typ" respectively, "tiefe_300" just gets lost / set to zeros. See screenshots below.

I have found [Shifted columns after Eliminate Polygon Part](https://community.esri.com/thread/184526-shifted-columns-after-eliminate-polygon-part) at GeoNet about a similar issue, but it has no solution on offer.

I suspect that there somehow exists a dependency on the order of the fields... but since I add the fields during processing I cannot do much about the original order.

How can I solve this problem?

*Before:*
[image: before]

*After:*
[image]

Comment: Make sure you've downloaded and applied all the 10.6.1 service packs. There was one that dealt with polygon topology issues.

Comment: @Vince: thanks for the hint - unfortunately all new patches did not help. Maybe I'll update to 10.8.1 and see how this works.

Comment: You should also repair polygon topology before running the eliminate.

Comment: @Vince the topology of the polygons is fine. The repair tool does not change anything. I found out that the problem is indeed the order of the attribute columns. When I export the feature class to a shapefile and reorder the attributes, such that the shape_length and shape_area columns stand last, the `eliminiate polygon part` tool works fine, without altering the columns. This is weird. How do I reorder the columns "in place"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved with a workaround as follows:

1. Run the dissolve tool on the feature class (checking the 4 fiels that need to persist later on - like this, shape_length and shape_area are moved to the end of the attribute table
2. Run eliminate polygon part tool after the dissolving - everything works well

This seems like a bug to me. It also exists in ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.1.